# cannot select the search bar on website and enter a key without getting a typeError

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to select and enter a string into a search bar however I receive a typeError: "str" object is not callable

ive tried selecting the element by ID, xpath, and Css selector to no avail. Ive also tried clicking the search bar after selecting it before entering the string which was also not effective.

```
driver.get("https://www.gsmarena.com")
searchBar = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR('#topsearch-text'))
searchBar.send_keys("iphone")
```

I want to be able to insert a string into the search bar and hit enter which should take me to the next page that contains a list of the phones that I am searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selecting the element by `input name` and use `Keys.ENTER` to search iphone.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("")

driver.get("https://www.gsmarena.com")
searchBar = driver.find_element_by_name('sSearch')
searchBar.send_keys("iphone")
searchBar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```